# outlook trying to access image through webdav in email signature

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, webdav, outlook-2010

I have an html email signature and 1 image on it which is hosted online. In Outlook 2010 it tries to get this through webdav which at atimes to users can take a while, once it fails then it gets it through http. How can i prevent this from happening?

log file on webserver

```
"PROPFIND /wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg HTTP/1.1" 405 358 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND /wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg HTTP/1.1" 405 358 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:26 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 200 234831 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
```

Also the image link is linked to use https but the logs below are from httpd access log, which makes no sense

Is there a way i can redirect this to a get?

from

```
"OPTIONS /wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
31.221.13.194 - - [26/Mar/2015:14:35:18 +0000] "PROPFIND /wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg HTTP/1.1" 405 358 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601"
```

to

```
"GET /wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 14063 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Comment: `How can i prevent this from happening?` - Stop using that signature?

Comment: I need to have an image in the signature but dont want it as an attacthment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the image
2. Insert the picture/image directly into the signature when you create the signature.  It won't show as an "attachment" if you are using HTML format.  If you want different signatures for each mail format (HTML, plain text, rich text) then you'd need something like Disclaimers (3rd party).
3. ....
4. Profit

Comment: This will create it as an attachment which i do not want.

Comment: It will be an embedded image in HTML, not an attachment.

Comment: this will increase the size of the email, which i also do not want.

Comment: @sharif something cake something...how big is the image?  Most signature images should only add a minimal amount of kb's to the email.  It's just a signature in an email, not some kid's signature on their favorite video game forum embedded with animated gifs etc.

Comment: http://www.spectrumgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/Spectrum_logo_email-171w.jpg when you email 50+ contacts back and forth it adds up in exchange.

Comment: That's a 13kb image.  No worries at all...I've seen them 3-4x that size and never had issues.